# sed repetition match misbehaving

Tags: regex, sed, pattern-matching

I am trying to get a file path from the following string:

```
"# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
```

by passing it to `sed`:

```
sed -n 's,\(# configuration file \)\(\/[a-zA-Z_.]\+\)\+,\1,'
```

I expect `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` be catched in `\1`, but surprisingly
only the `default.conf` part is returned. Here I understand that the referenced
part gets refilled each time with the next match of `/[a-zA-Z_.]\+`. Isn't it logical that
each next match goes to the next reference, so `default.conf` will be returned in `\4`?

```
/[a-zA-Z_.]\+ >>>

\(/etc\)\(/nginx\)\(/conf.d\)\(/default.conf\)
   \1        \2        \3           \4
```

Comment: Are both `"` part of the string?

Comment: You are missing `/` in character class. You may just use: `sed -E 's~# configuration file +(/[a-zA-Z/_.]+)+~\1~'`

Comment: And you need the second capture:
`echo "# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf" | sed -e 's,\(# configuration file \)\(\/[a-zA-Z_./]\+\)\+,\2,'` returns `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`.

Comment: @Cyrus, no `"` is not part of the string

Comment: @l00p: With `awk`: `echo "# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf" | awk '{print $NF}'`. `$NF` contains content of last column.

Comment: @EdMorton if nothing recursive happens, how it is possible that only `default.conf` is catched by `\1`? What about `/etc`, `/nginx` and `/conf.d` references?

Comment: @AlexanderMashin, @anubhava, yes, by adding a `/` into range specification, I will catch a full path, but I wanted to point out another problem, the way matched part was referenced. I will edit a question.

Comment: l00p now I understand where you're coming from so I've deleted my comment, see the NB statement in @potong's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE 's,(# configuration file )((/[a-zA-Z_.]+)+),\2,p' file
```

This will capture the file path.

```
sed -nE 's,(# configuration file )((/[a-zA-Z_.]+)+),\1,p' file
```

This will capture the beginning of the comment.

```
sed -nE 's/(# configuration file )((\/[a-zA-Z_.]+)+)/\3/p' file
```

This will capture the end of the file path.

N.B. When a capture group is qualified by something that maybe a repetition i.e. `*`,`?`,`+` or anything between `{...}` it will retain the last such repetition (see solution 3).

Comment: @EdMorton thanks. I'll amend one solution to use `/` as delimiters  to highlight the vestigial origins as to why it was escaped/quoted in the first place.